# How to implement a duration field?

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

I am constructing a content type that will 'wrap' a video, either youtube, vimeo or file upload. One of the fields required is a 'duration' field. Obviously a requirement is also for the videos to be sortable in a view based on that field.

How would I go about doing that? A format of `H:i:s` or `i:s` would be prefered in a textfield as an input method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Posting my comment as answer - Check for [HMS (Hours Minutes Seconds) Field](http://drupal.org/project/hms_field) module.

> Displays a integer formatted as Hours, Minutes or Seconds.
>   The field stores values as integer. Both input and output can be formatted as Hours, Minutes and/or Seconds. Alter functions provides developers a way to add their own format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module.  It will provide a cck date field, which you can configure as duration field

Comment: I've thought of that, but scemantically it's still a date. Is there a way to somehow get an actual duration type field?

Comment: Date and time field is good for a duration, However there is a time period module available, pls check that http://drupal.org/project/timeperiod also check http://drupal.org/project/interval

Comment: @AnoopJoseph mind if I add a module to that list ;) take a look at http://drupal.org/project/hms_field

Comment: @indrock add your module as a reply so I can checkmark it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **format_interval()**:

```
return format_interval(strtotime("2009-07-06") - strtotime("2007-06-01"));
// 2 years 1 month
```

Answer (score 0):

Also for Drupal 8 you can use - [Duration field](https://www.drupal.org/project/duration_field) module